# How to find the first term and common difference in AP?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic-progressions

> Given that $a_1,a_2,\dots$ is an arithmetic sequence. Let $a_3=-2$, $a_{21}=70$.
>
> Find the first term $a_1$ and common difference $d$.

---

The  $n$th term of arithmetic sequence is
$$a_n=a_1+d(n-1).$$

### Using the above formula how to find $a_1$ and $d$?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort. Also please use MathJax for mathematical formula and notations: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference Also... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression

Answer (score 0):

Though SE expects your effort, I give hint so that you can give your $50\%$ effort.

### Hint:

Given $$a_3 = a_1 + (3-1) d = -2 \tag{1}$$ and $$a_{21} = a_1 + (21-1) d = 70 \tag{2}$$.

So solving these two equation with two unknown $a_1$ and $d$, leads to answer??